# Continuous data with high likelihood does not look gaussian visually.

Tags: calculus, probability, density-function

I am trying to maximize the likelihood of a univariate gaussian for some $\mu$ and $\sigma$ given by below equation

$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{x - \mu}{\sigma})^2}
$$

My data $\mathbf{X} = [x_1, x_2] \in \mathbb{R}^2$ is producing high value for the joint density given by
$$
\begin{aligned}
f(x_1, x_2) &= f(x_1) . f(x_2|x_1)\\
\log f(x_1, x_2) &= \log f(x_1) + \log f(x_2|x_1)
\end{aligned}
$$

However, if I plot my 2D data with 256 data points (all of which outputs a high likelihood value), I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUb1c.png) plot which does not look like a Gaussian distribution, which should ideally look something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ys6j4.png). Ignore the color coding in both these images.

**My question is:**

What can be the possible reasons where the Gaussian likelihood for the data is high but it does not actually belong to a Gaussian distribution? Please note that this is a general question regarding the scenario where high likelihood does not actually imply the data belongs to the corresponding distribution. I am not looking for answers specific to my data $\mathbf{X}$ for which I haven't provided any details.

Any help is appreciated.

#### **Update**

I have added 3D html plots of $[x_0, x_1, f(x_0, x_1)]$ for an ideal case vs my case (You might need to download the html file and open in browser). The $f(x)$ is large for my plot and yet it does not form a normal distribution as expected. *FYI $f(x)$ is in terms of logarithms.*

[Ideal plot that I am expecting](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18pQeEh1e_x0upeLvez_Aa_uztzwuJ_So/view?usp=sharing)

[My plot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1astBQTGGFKsQsRSx4p8IwlWjoiFcJdH6/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: It is not clear whether you think you are dealing with univariate or bivariate cases.  In your first plot, you have what looks like a linear relationship and and (almost) perfect correlation so you should not be surprised is this associated with a very high conditional density

Comment: @Henry I added 3D plots in my update. Like you mentioned, the plot of $[x_0, x_1]$ looks like a perfect correction. But it does not look like a gaussian in my 3D plots with $f(x)$ values.  Can you expand your thoughts on this?